# Converting python lists to pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

If I have 3 python lists items:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = ['a','b','c']
list3 = ['I',"II","III"]
```

And my goal is to build a pd.DataFrame using list1 as index and the rest as columns:

```
     list2    list3
1     "a"     "I"
2     "b"     "II"
3     "c"     "III"
```

What would be the most efficient way to do it? Most of the similar questions I found here are joining *list of lists* or *dictionary*, but my data only has a simple structure and a natural order, so it should be simpler?

I have checked both `pd.Series` and `pd.DataFrame` documentation, but examples are also mostly about joining `Series` or `DataFrame` together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DataFrame constructor:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd, numpy as np

In [2]: list1 = [1,2,3]

In [3]: list2 = ['a','b','c']

In [4]: list3 = ['I',"II","III"]

In [5]: pd.DataFrame({'list2':list2,'list3':list3}, index=list1)
Out[5]: 
  list2 list3
1     a     I
2     b    II
3     c   III

In [6]:
```

Comment: I see, so the best way is to make all the list into a dictionary of list? Thanks! will accept as soon as the time passes!

Comment: @carl_pch No worries. Always happy to help a wahoo.